# Yii2 - Filtered Data In Grid View

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a test set-up which involves many to many relation.

```
Students Model
id
name

Parents Model
id
name

Students_Parents Model
student_id
parent_id
```

What I am trying to do is redirecting student update form to parent grid view. I want to show the related students parent records only in the parents grid view.

for example mysql query to show the related record is like this:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, p.id, p.name
FROM `students` s, parents p, student_parent sp
WHERE s.id = sp.student_id
AND p.id = sp.parent_id
AND s.id =102
```

and in the controller I could find the same record like this when I use the data of student with the id of 102

```
$model2 = Students_Parents::find()
            ->where(['student_id' => $model->id])
            ->all();
```

my redirect code in controller I am trying to do is:

```
if(isset($_POST['parents'])){
                   return $this->redirect(['parents/index','id'=>$model2]);
            }
```

Here the form is redirecting correctly, but no filter is applied.
How can I incorporate the query in redirect so I get the related data only in the GridView.

Thanks

Comment: In `return $this->redirect(['parents/index','id'=>$model2]);` - what is the value of `$model2`? Is it an integer?

Comment: @KunalDethe - Yes it is, it is the value of the ID

Answer (score 3):

You have to define in the redirect the name of the filter input as the key, like:

```
    $this->redirect(['parents/index','StudentSearch[id]'=>2]);
```